# How to replace shell module with command module in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I need one small help.

In below example I need to replace `shell` with `command` module. But I am confused as  `command` is not working with pipe.

So please give me the solution of this task. E.g:

```yaml
- name: Get the version
  become: true
  run_once: true
  shell: zypper pa | grep eric-odl | awk -F {'print $4'}
  register: odl_version
```

How I will split this task because each command output is dependent on next command?

Answer (score 1):

> *I need to replace `shell` with `command` module.*

Maybe you can provide more background information about the why and what you try to achieve.

Currently I guess according `man zypper` you try to

> *packages (pa) [options] [repository]...*
>
> *List all available packages or all packages from specified repositories. Similar to `zypper search -s -t package`.*

first and like to proceed further with something afterwards.

---

> *But I am confused `command` is not working with pipe.*

Right, that is the case and the intended behavior. See in example

- [`command` module – Execute commands on targets](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-command-module)

  > *The command(s) will not be processed through the shell, so variables like `$HOSTNAME` and operations like "`*`", "`<`", "`>`", "`|`", "`;`" and "`&`" will not work. Use the [ansible.builtin.shell](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-shell-module) module if you need these features.*
- [`shell` module – Execute shell commands on targets](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html)

  > *It is almost exactly like the [ansible.builtin.command](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-command-module) module but runs the command through a shell (`/bin/sh`) on the remote node.*
- [Whats the difference between ansible `raw`, `shell` and `command`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57805603/6771046)

---

> *So please give me the solution of this task*

There will be not "that solution" but you may have a look into the following list from most to least preferable approaches:

- Using [`package_facts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/package_facts_module.html) module in order to get package information as facts
- Evaluate [`zypper`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/zypper_module.html) module in order to manage packages on SUSE and openSUSE
- Using the `zypper` command in an other syntax which doesn't need
  `grep` and or `awk` like in

  - [Zypper: How do I display all packages from a certain repository?](https://superuser.com/questions/65560/)
  - [Zypper: How to list different available versions of a package?](https://superuser.com/questions/791907/)
  - [Zypper: How to list installed packages that are not in a repository?](https://superuser.com/a/1012047/754490)
  - any many more ...
- Or [writing an own Custom Module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73363872/6771046)
- Or using [`script`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/script_module.html) module in order to run a local script on a Remote Node after transferring it

Or, at least, just stay with `shell` for commands with pipes (and your given example as it is currently)